# Subset a tuple key dictionary into dictionaries with names based on keys

Tags: python, dictionary

The tuple key (key0, key1) dictionary(`df_dict`) I would like to subset has several dataframes in it, each dataframe has columns *date* and *accountNum*. I would like to subset `df_dict`and generate dictionary names based on key0.

```
df_dict = {('100', '001'): date, accountNum, ('100', '002'): date, accountNum, 
           ('200', '001'): date, accountNum, ('200', '002'): date, accountNum}
```

The dataframes in df_dict looks like the following,

```
('100','001')-DataFrame ('100','002')-DataFrame  ('200','001')-DataFrame 
date        accountNum   date        accountNum   data        accountNum
2010-01-01     280       2010-02-01     150       2010-03-01     330
2010-01-02     285       2010-02-02     155       2010-03-02     335
2010-01-03     290       2010-02-03     160       2010-03-03     340

('200','002')-DataFrame
date        accountNum
2010-04-01     510
2010-04-02     515
2010-04-03     520
```

The result I expected would be like,

```
df_dict_100 = {('100', '001'): date, accountNum, ('100','002'): date, accountNum}
df_dict_200 = {('200', '001'): date, accountNum, ('200','002'): date, accountNum}
```

And the data frame in each dictionary will be like,

```
df_dict100 
('100','001')-DataFrame ('100','002')-DataFrame   
date        accountNum   date        accountNum   
2010-01-01     280       2010-02-01     150       
2010-01-02     285       2010-02-02     155       
2010-01-03     290       2010-02-03     160    

df_dict200
('200','001')-DataFrame  ('200','002')-DataFrame
date        accountNum   date         accountNum
2010-01-01     280       2010-04-01     510
2010-01-02     285       2010-04-02     515
2010-01-03     290       2010-04-03     520
```

This is my approach,

```
my_list = ['100','200']
subset_dict = {k: v for k, v in df_dict.items() if k[0] in my_list}
```

but seems like I got the exact dictionary from `df_dict`.

Comment: I'm assuming `date` and `accountNum` are meant to be in a tuple in each of the keys? As your current syntax would raise an error.

Comment: `df_dict = {('100', '001'): date, accountNum, ('100', '002'): date, accountNum,` gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing to the `,` after the first `accountNum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the first form to something like the second form by creating a multi-level dictionary. So, rather than `df_dict_100`, you might have `df_dict[100]`, like so:

```
import pprint

date, accountNum = 'date', 'accountNum'
df_dict = {('100', '001'): (date, accountNum), ('100', '002'): (date, accountNum),
           ('200', '001'): (date, accountNum), ('200', '002'): (date, accountNum)}

new_dict = dict()
for key, value in df_dict.items():
    new_dict.setdefault(key[0], {})[key] = value

pprint.pprint(new_dict)
```

The result is then:

```
{'100': {('100', '001'): ('date', 'accountNum'),
         ('100', '002'): ('date', 'accountNum')},
 '200': {('200', '001'): ('date', 'accountNum'),
         ('200', '002'): ('date', 'accountNum')}}
```

To access an individual datum, you might use syntax like:

```
print(new_dict['100']['100', '001'][0])
```

If you prefer a dict comprehension, try this:

```
subset_dict = {
    matching_key : {
        k: v for k, v in df_dict.items() if k[0] == matching_key }
    for matching_key in set(k[0] for k in df_dict)
}
```

In a comment, OP asks "*may I know how to generate two dictionaries rather than two dictionaries in one dictionary*?" Something like this should work:

```
df_dict_100 = { k: v for k, v in df_dict.items() if k[0] == '100' }
df_dict_200 = { k: v for k, v in df_dict.items() if k[0] == '200' }
```

Putting those together into a `for` loop, here is a complete program:

```
import pprint

date, accountNum = 'date', 'accountNum'
df_dict = {('100', '001'): (date, accountNum), ('100', '002'): (date, accountNum),
           ('200', '001'): (date, accountNum), ('200', '002'): (date, accountNum)}

my_list = ['100', '200']
for i in my_list:
    new_df_dict = { k: v for k, v in df_dict.items() if k[0] == i }
    pprint.pprint(new_df_dict)
    print("----")
```

And here is the output:

```
{('100', '001'): ('date', 'accountNum'),
 ('100', '002'): ('date', 'accountNum')}
----
{('200', '001'): ('date', 'accountNum'),
 ('200', '002'): ('date', 'accountNum')}
----
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob. This is great! But may I know how to generate two dictionaries rather than two dictionaries in one dictionary(subset_dict)?

Comment: Sure, just unroll the outer loop. See my recent edit.

Comment: Is it possible to generate two dictionaries at once so that we don't need to write the commends `df_dict_100 = {k: v for k, v in df_dict.items() if k[0] == '100'}` and `df_dict_200 = { k: v for k, v in df_dict.items() if k[0] == '200' }`

Comment: This is what I did, but it only generates dictionary with `k[0] = 100` .  Created a list first, `my_list = ['100', '200']` and run the for loop, `for i in my_list:
    new_df_dict = {k: df_dict[k] for k in df_dict if k[0] == i}`

Comment: I've added an example of using a `for i in my_list:` loop at the end of my answer.